# Will Shard return the result from one core if other core is down?

Tags: solr, sharding

I'm using shard query to get response from two different core on two different system, one from say hybris and other from OTMM. Now if my OTMM server is down shard query is not returning the result from other solr which is up. it is giving error as:

morg.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at .XXXX.net:8983/solr/otmm
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/11/04 03:24:55.476 |     at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:560)

Do i need to configure anything to get result from one server if other is down. I'm using below code after adding fqs in param:

response = solr.query(params);

Comment: Atleast one replica of the shard should be active. say shard1 is in node1 and node2, one of them is leader node.  if both node1 & node2 is down you cannot get results of that shard.

Answer (score 0):

If you want results even when one of your shards is down, you need to ensure that a replica for that shard is up and serving requests.

If you do not want to create replicas and instead want your remaining shard to serve the request, then you can append the `distrib=false` parameter in your query and provide the correct shard address in the `shard` parameter.

Such a query would look something like this:

`/myhandler?q=something&distrib=false&shards=othershard:8888/solr/core`